# What would happen if i change the UUID serial version of the entity class?

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, spring-data-jpa

Say entity class Employee is like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")    
class Employee implements Serializable{    
private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;    
int id;    
String name;    
public Student(int id, String name) {    
this.id = id;    
this.name = name;    
}
```

Now during next deployment i change

```
private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;
```

to

```
private static final long serialVersionUID=123L;
```

What will be the consequences?

Yet to try this out in real world applications. Any headsup on this or if anyone has tried it?`your text`

Answer (score 0):

When you change the value of the serialVersionUID field in the Employee class, it can cause problems when serializing and deserializing objects.

The serialVersionUID is used as an identifier for the serialized version of an object. It ensures that the serialized object matches the class definition when it is being deserialized.

If you change the serialVersionUID to a different value, it means the serialized object is different from what is expected during deserialization. This can result in errors when trying to deserialize the object.

Additionally, if you have previously serialized instances of the Employee class with the old serialVersionUID, trying to deserialize them with the updated serialVersionUID may fail. The serialized data is checked against the serialVersionUID for compatibility, and a mismatch can lead to deserialization errors.

To avoid these issues, it's important to manage the serialVersionUID carefully when making changes to serialized classes. If you make incompatible changes to the class structure, consider incrementing the serialVersionUID to indicate the incompatibility and handle deserialization failures gracefully.

Keeping backward compatibility in mind when serializing and deserializing objects helps prevent unexpected issues during deployment and application updates.